# Confluent Kafka Cloud SSL Setup

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

I have created a Topic in Confluent Cloud. Would this Topic already have SSL setup or is it something that needs to be setup manually? As far I can see there was no option to enable / setup SSL in confluent cloud, so I assumed it is automatically being set. How can X.509 certificate be generated for this topic to be used in the Kafka client?

Comment: Certificates would be cluster, not topic, specific.